# shortcode in model page in twentytwelve theme?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I create a page in the model twentytwelve theme and I install the plugin cool video galery. my problem if I create  it shows me the shortcode, not the video, how do I correct the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function for using shortcode in Template.

So, Suppose if you short code is `[cvg-gallery galleryId='gallery-id']` then wrap it with do_shotcode. Like

```
// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
echo do_shortcode('[cvg-gallery galleryId='gallery-id']');
```

And then use it in template or in Lightbox.

Comment: yes yes , if i write 
[cvg-gallery galleryId='gallery-id']
in content in a page , it's OK, but if I write do_shortcode(...) in model page , this show me a String (the string of shortcode) ?